# How to troubleshoot seaborn legend_out not working correctly with catplot or relplot?

Tags: seaborn, jupyter-lab

With seaborn 0.11.1 and matplotlib 3.3.4 this...

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

print(sns.__version__, mpl.__version__)

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
plt.show()
```

...the result is supposed to look like this:

[image]

However, when I do that in JupyterLab or Plotly-Dash I get:

[image]

I deleted `~/.config/matplotlib` and setup a clean conda environment with minimal packages. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = False
```

fixes it.